# How can I count List in Task?

Tags: c#, list, count, task

```
private async Task<List<T>> Ex_Event(string telNo)
{
    SearchConditionData scd = new SearchConditionData { tel=telNo };            
    List<T> list = await RequestAsync<SearchConditionData, List<T>>(scd, Service.GetIncident);

    historyList = ( ... ).Take(30).ToList();          

    return historyList;
}
```

I made a method that returns List<>.

But I modified it async, then I can't use List.Count.

Here are some part of my code.

```
public delegate Task<List<IncidentListData>> HistoryEvent(string telNo);
public event HistoryEvent myHistoryEvent;
```

**Return Type is Task<>. And I want to check the count List in Task.**

```
if (myHistoryEvent(Tel).Count > 0)
```

But it does not work. And I can't use async, because I called myHistoryEvent() in Interface that `public string this[string name]` (IDataErrorInfo)

How Can I check the count of List in Task??

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on this, you should probably try to understand the basics first.

Comment: Give some of the tons back then, only stating that doesn't help much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check with result of your task.

```
myHistoryEvent(Tel).Result.Count > 0
```

Inside result type List Task>.Result.